# asp.net mvc resource cannot be found controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, controller

i got stack on my project the problem is after adding new controller class and views for the actions unable to link the views with existing views
*

> The resource cannot be found

.*
i have home and account controller classes which work well and i add new controller class users and i have to action methods index and adduser both have view but anytime when i try to retrieve view from the new controller class it dosnt found the pages.
eg <%= Html.ActionLink("users", "Index", "users")%>  please help !!!

Comment: You're going to need to provide more information.

Comment: +1. I think it should be mandatory to post some of the code for those who have rep<1000

Answer (score 1):

have you created views?

Guideline:

1. create controller  `controller_nameController`
2. create action        `public actionresult action_name(){return View();}`
3. create views          Hit `ctrl+m, ctrl+v` or right click on the action whose view you would like to create.

[image]
4. check if you really have created a view named `action_name` in `controller_name folder`

[image]

Then you can create links: `("to display text", "action name", "controller name")`

Hope this helps.

Comment: yeah i created both the action and the controller i.e Index view and Index action name on users controller

Comment: @TeddyTeddy - is it called UsersController? or just Users?

Comment: `ControllerName` in asp.net mvc follows this simple rule: `ControllerNameController`. e.g. `Users` controller should be named: `UsersController`

Comment: @Anubhav Saini Userscontroller

Comment: @TeddyTeddy what? if your View Folder Name is `Users`, your controller name is `UsersController`! what are you asking?